# Not able to comprehend the array statement of last line

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(9, dtype = "float").reshape(3,3)
ind1 = np.array([[1,2],[0,1]])
ind2 = np.array([[0,2],[1,2]])
print(arr[ind1, ind2].sum())
```

Output for the given code coming out to be 17.0 but i am not able to understand how is the arr[ind1,ind2] working.Kindly help!

Comment: You should read about indexing multidimensional arrays in NumPy.

Answer (score 0):

firstly, solve this thing arr[ind1,ind2] 
as ind1 and ind2 both are matrices of 2*2. Now we have to pair the corresponding positions of both the matrices. which results in 4 pairs : (1,0) ; (0,1) ; (2,2) ; (1,2) .

Now find the values from arr which are at these positions.
and values comes out to be 3;1;8;5 respectively. now there is .sum() operation . 
So just simply add these values. and the result comes out to be 17.

Hope I clarified your doubt.